# converting user input date (ddmmyyyy) to another format (%d/%m/%Y)

Tags: bash

I am starting to learn about shell scripting in school now and one of my assignment was to write a shell script menu to view user backup from a particular BackupLogFile.dat. As I was trying to figure out how to write the date, i met with this problem which i can't convert the date format to the date format in the BackupLogFile.dat file (eg. 1/9/2012) and the user input data is formatted (ddmmyyyy). I tried writing the script as below but i didn't work. really appreciate someone can point to me where did I go wrong. Thanks :)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter the date (ddmmyyyy): "
read answer
date=$answer-'+%d/%m/%Y' | grep BackupLogFile.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
```